# Condition formatting in Excel. Find non-matching values between columns

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns; quantity ordered and quantity shipped.

If and order is 100% filled those values should match on each row.

I want to write a conditional format that highlights quantity shipped if it is less than quantity ordered on the same row.

I can compare values between columns but have been unable to specify that the comparison is on the same row.

Comment: Conditional formatting - highlight cells less than - select the quantity ordered cell and remove the `$` before the row number... then copy/paste formats down the column.

Comment: @BigBen Perfect. Thank you.